# How to mock camel endpoints in separate camel context

Tags: apache-camel

I am writing test cases for a library that hides camel business from end users.
The library exposes methods such as sendMessages() etc and internally using ProducerTemplate sends the messages on to a camel route where they are aggregated and sent to destination eventually.

I want to be able to write tests that call the library method and mock the camel route endpoints to do asserts on it later.

If I use CamelSpringTestSupport, it basically creates a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, using which i can test the routes.

However I want to test the endpoints which are created within the library's camel contextso that I test-cover the library code as well.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Camel's [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) to dynamically change the route behavior (intercept exchanges and send to mock endpoints for validation, etc)...its very flexible and leverages the familiar MockEndpoints, etc...

for example...to intercept the messages sent to the `direct:start` route

```
context.getRouteDefinition("myRouteId").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:start")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .to("mock:start");
    }
});

getMockEndpoint("mock:start").expectedBodiesReceived("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

My final test case looks like following, where existing context's routes get mocked.

```java
    import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
    import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithRouteBuilder;
    import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
    import org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestSupport;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class MyAppTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    private static MyApp myapp;
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAppTest.class);

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return (AbstractApplicationContext) myApp.getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        // tell we are using advice with, which allows us to advice the route
        // before Camel is being started, and thus can replace myApp Endpoint with something else.
        return true;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp() throws Exception {
        myApp = new myApp();
    }

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test01() throws Exception {

        log.info("TEST: Going to apply advideWith clause to existing route");

        context.getRouteDefinition("bulkIndexRoute").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                weaveByToString(".*myAppEndpoint.*")
                        .replace()
                        .aggregate(header("ABC"), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
                        .completionSize(100)
                        .completionInterval(1000)
                        .to("mock:foo");
            }
        });
        log.info("TEST: Done applying adviceWith Clause");

        MockEndpoint mockedES = getMockEndpoint("mock:foo");
        mockedES.expectedMessageCount(2);
        mockedES.setAssertPeriod(10000);

        // Create 150 test documents and index them
        for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
            Map<String, String> d = new HashMap<String, String>();
            d.put("key1", "value" + i);
            d.put("key2", "value" + i);
            myApp.send("param1", "param2", d);
        }

        mockedES.assertIsSatisfied();

        int count = 0;
        for(Exchange ex : mockedES.getExchanges()){
            List<Map<String, Object>> documentList = ex.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            count += documentList.size();
        }

        Assert.assertEquals("Received back 150 message", 150, count);
    }
}
```

MyApp class returns the context to the test, so that routes in the running context can be mocked.